# The Fourier transform of $x \mapsto |x|^{-1/3}e^{-x^{2}}$ is not in $L^{1}$.

Tags: measure-theory, integration, fourier-analysis

Okay previously my lecturer showed that this is so by proving in the following way:

Proof by contradiction. Suppose the transform is in $L^{1}$. Then as $f \in L^1$, we may use Fourier Inversion Formula thereby getting $$ f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \widehat f(t) e^{2\pi i xt} dt. $$ Therefore, $f$ is bounded almost everywhere and therefore globally.

Is this proof correct? I think according to my previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219301/if-a-function-is-bounded-almost-everywhere-then-globally-bounded), it seems not. If this proof is incorrect, can I modify? Or change it entirely and if then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument works here as $f$ can be represented by a continuous function (this can be seen by the inversion transform formula). So if $|f(x)|\leq M$ for almost every $x$, say for $x\in \Bbb R\setminus N$, where $\lambda(N)=0$, then $\lambda$ has an empty interior, so $\Bbb R\setminus N$ is dense in $\Bbb R$. We conclude by continuity.

This proves that if an integrable function $f$ has a Fourier transform which is integrable, then $f$ is bounded.

For the particular case in the OP, note that $f$ is not (essentially) bounded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So what I was missing was the continuity, I just realized. Thasnk for it!